# I am getting the following error after installing Catboost. ImportError: Module use of python36.dll conflicts with this version of Python

Tags: catboost

I installed from wheel and there were no issues in installation. But while importing into my program I am getting errors.

Answer (score 1):

Check that you run your .py script (where import catboost) with right python version